# DatePicker Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am in need of date picker javascript which allows date in mm/dd/yy format.

And also it should have good resolution and should be non-popup based.

I searched in google  but not getting my exact requirements.

Plz suggest me the proper source.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), especially the [display Inline](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline) example.